# prop returns Null when component renders

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, react-redux, axios

I am trying to add some functionality that enables or disables a button depending on whether the user has at least one "credit". I want to use the logical && to determine whether to enabled or disabled the button. The parent component fetches the current user asynchronously, which should give the component access to the user model and the users credits.

CHILD COMPONENT:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import SurveyList from './surveys/SurveyList';

class Dashboard extends Component {
    render() {
        console.log(this.props);
        return (
            <div>
                <SurveyList />
                <div className="fixed-action-btn"> 
                    {this.props.auth.credits && 
                      <Link to="/surveys/new" className="btn-floating btn-large red">
                      <i className="material-icons">add</i>
                      </Link>
                    }
                    <button className="btn-floating btn-large disabled red">
                    <i className="material-icons">add</i>
                    </button>
                 </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
};
function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        auth: state.auth
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Dashboard);
```

PARENT COMPONENT:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Header from './Header';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import * as actions from '../actions';
import Landing from './Landing';
import Dashboard from './Dashboard';
import NewList from './lists/NewList';



class App extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.fetchUser();
    }
    render() {
        console.log(this.props);
        return (
            <div className="container">
                <BrowserRouter>
                    <div>
                        <Header />
                        <Route exact path='/' component={Landing} />
                        <Route exact path='/surveys' component={Dashboard} />
                        <Route path='/surveys/new' component={NewList} />
                    </div>
                </BrowserRouter>
            </div>
        );
    }
};

export default connect(null, actions)(App);
```

ACTION:

```
export const fetchUser = () => async dispatch => {
    const res = await axios.get('/api/currentUser')
    dispatch({ type: FETCH_USER, payload: res.data});
};
```

Comment: Your question is not a question, it's a description of what you want to do and the title doesn't have anything to do with your description. Please give it a try yourself first and pinpoint and explain what's going wrong and where we can help.

Comment: @DenniedeLange how does the title not relate to the description? The title describes what's going wrong and the description explains the code that's the source of the problem.

Comment: @DenniedeLange I have a console.log(this.props) line in the <Dashboard /> component. When the component renders, the console statement fires twice. The first time it fires, this.props.auth.credits is Null (hence why I titled it as such). The second time it fires, this.props.auth.credits is not Null and has the value I want. I think this is because the parent component makes an async call to get the the current user (action snippet), which contains the auth.credits part. To phrase the question better, how do I wait for that prop to have a value or for the request to be made before rendering?

Comment: That's much better, you're explaining now what "prop" is and what's happening. You're correct about the rerendering, so an additional check should suffice `this.props.auth && this.props.auth.credits &&..`

Comment: @DenniedeLange yep, that did it. Thank you. Not sure how to mark your answer as accepted/correct

Comment: I shouldn't have answered in the comments. I added an answer as well now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an additional check `this.props.auth && this.props.auth.credits &&..`.